# Why we have to add get() after a private var in fragment for view binding?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments

### I was following the google codelab. There I came across the following code:

```kotlin
class Calculator: Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentCalculatorBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
}
```

**What is the need for the `get()`?**

We can do this in the following way:

```kotlin
class Calculator: Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentCalculatorBinding? = null
    private val binding = _binding!!
}
```

### The explaination given there was:

Here, `get()` means this property is "get-only". That means you can get the value, but once assigned (as it is here), you can't assign it to something else.

but I don't understand it. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point in having a second property here is to allow the first property to be set back to null. (The second property is for convenience and should only be used when the fragment is known to be attached to an Activity.) Using a getter means it does the evaluation `_binding!!` each time it is accessed. Without `get()` it evaluates it once when the class is instantiated and assigns the result to a backing field. Since `_binding` is null at class instantiation time, this would be guaranteed to fail. And even if it didn’t fail, it would have an outdated reference if the fragment got detached and reattached.

Your description of what “get only” means is inverted. Either the code lab got their explanation backwards or you paraphrased it backwards.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you don't. It's very messy in my opinion.

Simply use:

```
private lateinit var binding: FragmentCalculatorBinding
```

It's does the same thing as your existing code - throws exception if you use the variable before instantiate it.

Keep in mind that you must instantiate it before using it (the whole point of `lateinit var`).

Comment: `lateinit` will leak the views because it prevents you from dropping the binding reference when the fragment is detached.  That’s the reason the documentation tells you to use two properties like this for fragments, but for activities they do tell you to use just a `lateinit` property (activities are never detached and reused).

Comment: Nope, because it's only referenced from the fragment. Meaning that it'll be collected by GC after the fragment will be collected. Also, when you override the value, the old value will also be collected by GC. Bottom line it's memory-save.

Comment: Fragments can be detached from an Activity and kept in memory until reused. This is why `getContext()` and `getActivity()` return nullables, and is also why they tell you in the documentation to keep your binding property nullable, and to null out the reference in `onDestroyView()`. In the documentation and in their code labs, they repeat this pattern, while they simply use `lateinit` for the binding in an Activity, since Activity instances are not reused.

Comment: The `binding` property here is analogous to `requireContext()`. It's a non-null-asserted version of the nullable property, provided because most Fragment code is called while a Fragment is attached, so it is convenient to have a non-null-asserted version of the property. You could make an argument that the views are only temporarily leaked since the Fragment will eventually either be reused or surrendered to the GC, and therefore maybe convenience outweighs correctness. But it is not correct to say `lateinit` is equivalent. There are pros and cons.

Comment: The fragment should not be detached forever (if so, your fragments are not maintained correctly). So yeah, the binding will still be referenced but it's not considered a memory leak since the fragment is still in use (even if detached). Next time `onCreateView` will be called and you'll override new value. Keep in mind that detached state should be super-temporary for fragments

Comment: I use the term *leak* informally, but it is holding onto more memory than necessary. Google understands their lifecycle and recommends nulling it out, so there is a difference in behavior using `lateinit`.

Comment: I always understood your point. But, in my opinion, it's an overkill and Google recommends over-optimizing the code unnecessarily (eventually it'll get collected and quickly since fragment's are detached only for a short time), resulting in quite ugly code. That being said, I stand behind my answer. You may not like it or accept it, but it's here to stay.

Comment: I agree with you. I “cheat” and use `lateinit` too. But the OP is a Kotlin newbie asking what this arrangement of properties does so telling them it’s the same as `lateinit` without explanation is confusing them about Kotlin syntax and patterns.

Comment: Well, it's indeed a trade off. I wish you luck :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use it like this, you have a very explicit way of setting `binding` - you have to do it using `_binding` (which would probably just happen once in `onCreateView()`. For all the places where you actually use it, you would use `binding`, which both checks if `_banding` has actually been set, and cannot accidentally be changed as it is immutable, thereby saving you from potential bugs.

That being said - I would probably go with a `lateinit var` as well, and lose all the null checking, but that is a matter of personal taste I think.

Answer (score 0):

using get() after the variable name makes it assign to the value when we each time trying to access this variable
as mentioned above without get() the variable will be assigned immediately when this class instantiated